# Not getting 2d-fft invrese of an image from kissfft

Tags: c, fft, ifft, kissfft

I am getting the 2d-fft of an image properly, 
But not getting the inverse of from the 2d-fft of that same image.
              What are the proper calls for getting inverse from the 2d-fft of that same image ???

```
// for 2d-fft. This I am getting properly
kiss_fftnd_cfg st = kiss_fftnd_alloc(dims, ndims, 0, 0, 0);
kiss_fftnd(st,(kiss_fft_cpx *)fftbuf,(kiss_fft_cpx *)fftoutbuf);

// for inverse. By using this I am getting the wrong values.
kiss_fftndr_cfg st2 = kiss_fftndr_alloc(dims, ndims, 1, 0, 0);
kiss_fftndri(st2, (kiss_fft_cpx *)fftoutbuf, (kiss_fft_scalar *)obuf);

// even I have tried this. By using this I am getting the wrong values.
kiss_fftr_cfg st3 = kiss_fftr_alloc( (rows * cols) , 1, 0, 0);
kiss_fftri( st3 , (kiss_fft_cpx *)fftoutbuf ,(kiss_fft_scalar *)rbuf);
```

Comment: Your input is complex, why do use a real-valued inverse? Did you try a normal complex-valued inverse?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing complex and real FFTs.

The forward/inverse behavior is controlled by the 3rd argument `inverse_fft` of the *alloc functions (i.e. complex `kiss_fftnd_alloc` and real `kiss_fftndr_alloc` ).